# Formula for 3 different measurement scales

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not quite sure what this is called, but here's my problem.
I have 3 different measurement ranges that correspond with one another.

1. **The Adjustment Potentiometer** - This adjustment outputs a value from **0 to 1024**, based on the knob's position.
2. **The Adjustment Levels** - The levels being set range from **0 to 255**.  So if the potentiometer is set to 1024, the value should be converted to 255.  I'm not sure how to convert the 0-1024 to correspond to the 0-255 range.
3. **The Human Readable Scale** - A scale of **0 to 100** makes for a much more human readable scale, so I would like to output the value within this range.

I'm not quite sure how to convert one scale to the other and greatly appreciate anyone who can teach me the correct formula.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this work: $ap = $ setting of the potentiometer, $f_{al} = 0.2490234375 \times ap, f_{hr} = 0.09765624999999999 \times al$? So, if we set the $ap = 1024$, we get  $f_{al} = 255, f_{hr} = 100$?

Comment: Of course, this can be combined into a single formula that goes from potentiometer setting right to human readable.

Comment: Ok, I see how you did that.  Thank you very much for this!